# How to fix "The Rename refactoring cannot be applied in this context" with CPP in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

is there a solution to refactor CPP code using Apache NetBeans IDE 16 with MacOS ?
Right now if I select a variable then "Rename" from the "Refactor" menu I get this message:  "The Rename refactoring cannot be applied in this context", whatever kind of variable (local or global).
I'm a Netbeans user for years now with java, that's why I'm testing the tool for C++, but if that refactoring feature is not available for c++ I will change my mind for another IDE. Any suggestion ?  (I code for Arduino, and the Arduino IDE also does not provide refactoring).

Thanks

Comment: what is the context?

Comment: don't know, the problem is for all variables I've been trying to rename, local in a function or global in a header file .h or in a .c file

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, and the only suggestion I have is to [raise a bug report with NetBeans](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues). NetBeans support for C/C++ generally seems to have gone downhill over the past few years.

Comment: O/T, but two people have voted to close this question because it _"Needs details or clarity"_. The first two sentences of this question clearly and unambiguously describe the problem. Anyone who has ever used NetBeans to develop C++ applications would immediately understand the issue, and adding further details would be counterproductive. Ignorant close voters are a menace to this site!